# Opening Solution / Project with Visual studio 2015 when there is no sln file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, box2d

I just downloaded open source code at github https://github.com/alextrevisan/SFML-LiquidFun-Water
And, I opened visual studio 2015 and tried to open it but there is no such thing like .sln file..
In this situation how can I open the project?? and where am I supposed to locate all that files at.
[image]

Comment: Open the `.cpb` file by [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

Comment: Want to know how to solve with visual if okay..

Comment: oh so u mean that source code is written by CodeBlocks not visual api?

Comment: Yes, exactly. BTW, how do you install `Box2d`? No documentation.

Comment: Yeap that is another problem I am in, I downloaded Box2D and built it, but after opening above project, I have no idea how to import that library.

Answer (score 2):

Try File->New->Project from existing code. Then select the source folder and compile.

You may have to make a few selections in the wizard (such as whether it's a console app or if some dependencies are needed), depending on what the original code::blocks project had set. But if it's standard compliant C++, it should compile and run without any fancy compiler settings.

Answer (score -1):

As previously mentioned, the project you are trying to open in Visual Studio, is a Code::Blocks one. So, I would suggest to you downloading CB 16.*, which is open source. In the Project's folder you can see:

*.cbp: it is the principal file of the Project. An XML: just open it or double click on it to open the Project (it will organise your headers and sources files as Visual Studio does).

*.layout: another XML.

*.depend: it contains the header files included in the Project.

Review your header files and your source files to find out in which version of C++ the project has been developed (C++98? C++11?).

1) Goto Project > Build options... and check the version of C++ you want your Project to compile on, as shown in the below image:

[image]

2) Then, goto Project > Properties... > Project's build options... and check again the version of C++ compiler.

[Note: This will work for your current project. If you want to setup CB toolchain for all your future projects, then goto: Settings > Compiler > Compiler Settings, and check the corresponding box. In Settings > Compiler > toolchain executables: you will find all the default executables, which you can change as per your own convenience.]

CB is a very easy to use tool, and can be installed both in Windows and Linux. Actually, if you google it, you will find information about how to build up your Box2D tool.

Please, check: http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8159